# HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error -jsp-tomcat - (Dockerfile)

Tags: mysql, docker, github, containers, tomcat8

As a beginner to Docker, I'm building a simple web application that register/login users. When I build the image I get the following error HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error Building web application in **Docker file** and I have linked containers (tomcat and MySQL). I've also downloaded and added the jar file. Don't know what went wrong and couldn't find any helpful answer on google as yet. I'm getting the same error for both the JSP(one for login and another for register)files in my project.<

> **Dockerfile (mysql)**

```
FROM mysql

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="vprodbpass"
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE="accounts"

ADD db_backup.sql docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/accountsdb.sql
```

> **Dockerfile (tomcat:8-jre8)**

```
FROM tomcat:8-jre8

RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/*

COPY vprofile-v1.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

> **Docker Images**

```
XXXXXXX@krushna:~/training/docker/vpdocker/vproapp$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
vproileapp          latest              609ea8d2ddc3        24 seconds ago      481MB
vprofiledb          latest              856d8b3af123        5 minutes ago       486MB
tomcat              8-jre8              78b258e36eed        2 weeks ago         463MB
mysql               latest              f991c20cb508        3 weeks ago         486MB
```

> **Creating vrprodb container**

```
 sudo docker run --name vprodb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=vprodbpass -p 3306:3306 -d vprofiledb
```

> **Creating vproapp container**

```
 sudo docker run --name vproapp --link vprodb:mysql -p 7070:8080 -d vprofileapp
```

> **Running containers**

```
XXXXXX@krushna:~/training/docker/vpdocker/vproapp$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
535ac19c6498        vproileapp          "catalina.sh run"        11 seconds ago      Up 7 seconds        0.0.0.0:7070->8080/tcp              vproapp
40807697bd06        vprofiledb          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   vprodb
```

> **when I try to host it shows this error (localhost:7070)**

**HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error**

```
Type Exception Report

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not open connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not open connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:120)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)

Root Cause
```

Comment: Could you also share the database config/properties you use for spring?

Comment: It is clear that there is a problem to connect to the DB. Please also include the next few lines of the stack trace (starting with "Root Cause").

Comment: Did you make sure the DB was fully started up when you launched the app container?

Comment: [Github] (https://github.com/wkhanvisualpathit/VProfile/blob/vp-docker/src/main/resources/db_backup.sql )@sven

Comment: Your password in application.properties does not match the one in your Mysql build. Make sure these match and try again

Comment: can you give me more clarification on (MySQL build) @SvenHakvoort

Comment: In the dockerfile you have `vpropass` as password and in https://github.com/wkhanvisualpathit/VProfile/blob/vp-docker/src/main/resources/application.properties you have it  as `vprodbpass`

Comment: After updating the correct password in my Docker file(MySQL) do I need to build the image(updated password docker file)  from the scratch? so that I can host my web application. or is there any alternate way? @SvenHakvoort

Comment: Yes you need to build the image again, or you can start it with `-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=newpw` in order to overwrite the env variable specified in the docker file. I would recommend the latter in all cases and just remove the password from your Dockerfile since this is less dynamic

Comment: sure, once I build the image I will update my status @SvenHakvoort

Comment: I have updated the password(prodbpass) both in Docker file and command line(-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=newpw) but the result same  @Sven Hakvoort